# How to convert images already stored in MySQL database to images stored locally

Tags: java, mysql, image

I have built a software using Java and MySQL.
Its functionality is to receive **Images** and store them into a database (MySQL).
I did this for ease of backup. But now I realized that the stress on the database is increasing. So, I have decided to convert all the **Images** currently in the database with about 306 rows to stored them locally with their path on the system. How do I go about this, to avoid reentering the data?

Comment: You have to make a small program to extract the blob data from MySQL and store it in a file with a name that you can link with the record

Comment: Plus: Think about using local caches for the images if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all images and save them locally use following code :

> by Using SELECT image FROM TABLE
>
> then use this code in LOOP

```
 private static void save(BufferedImage image, String fileName,String ext) {

        File file = new File(fileName + "." + ext);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, ext, file);  // ignore returned boolean
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Write error for " + file.getPath() +
                               ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image src) {
        int w = src.getWidth(null);
        int h = src.getHeight(null);
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;  // other options
        BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
        return dest;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response .Will try it.Will also create a column for path and update it with the fileName.